# The tangent space $TV$ of a smooth (irreducible) algebraic variety $V$ is smooth and irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I know that if $V\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$, $TV$ can be seen as an algebraic set contained in $\mathbb{A^{2n}}$ given by the collection $\{(v,\delta): v\in V, \delta \in T_vV\}$.

In general even if $V$ is an algebraic variety (i.e. it is irreducible), $TV$ might not be a variety. For example if $V=V(y^2-x^3)$. I know that the problem here somehow lies in the fact that the point $(0,0)$ has tangent space of strictly bigger dimension than $V$ (i.e. the point is not smooth).

However, for the irreducible and smooth case, I cannot manage to prove either irreducibility or smoothnes of $TV$. Could you give me any hints or some reference where I can have a look at the proof of this fact?

Comment: Hartshorne, chapter II.8 should essentially cover this, but depending on you background this might be to technical. Essentially, you can cover $V$ by open sets $U$, such that $TV \to V$ is locally isomorphic to a projection $U \times \mathbb A^k \to U$, where $k = \dim V$.